# How to create Dynamic pipelines to copy data from multiple on-prem SQL servers to a single server

Tags: azure-data-factory

Could you please help me on this.

We have multiple on-prem SQL servers and the servers are keep on getting added frequently.
We need to dynamically connect to these servers and copy data from the tables to a single on-prem sql server.

How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Hi @TechSavy Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Hi @TechSavy, Please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @HarrisXu foryour reply. Yes it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can follow this [post](https://visualbi.com/blogs/microsoft/azure/parameterize-connections-azure-data-factory/) to do parameterize linked services, dynamic incoming connection string information.
[image]

1. Declare an Array type variable. Add default value `[{"ServerName": "server1","DBName": "Test","UserName":"sa","Password": "****","TableName":"t_user"}, {"ServerName": "server2","DBName": "Test","UserName":"sa","Password": "***","TableName":"t_user"}]`
   [image]
2. Then foreach the array, Add dynamic content  `@pipeline().parameters.LinkArray`.
   [image]
3. Edit the linked service properties. It will dynamically pass the value in. So we can connect to different servers.
   [image]